# How to modularize resources used by .war

Tags: resources, war, websphere-liberty

I have a simple Spring/Gradle/Liberty REST service that I would like to deploy on several different servers, with each deployment having different resources (e.g., connection parameters).  Is there some way to keep the resource folder(s) separately from the .war, so that I can build and deploy the same .war to all deployments and only supply *somehow* the per-deployment resource folders?

Comment: are these resources just configuration-type things?  If so, environment variables sound like a good option.  If not, you'll have to give more examples  of the resources you are referring to

Comment: Resources include:  XML file with bean definitions, properties file, .yml file used for OAuth2, and some logger setting files.

Comment: Assuming the resources are loaded through getResource() calls, a shared library might be the way to go - you can add a directory entry to a shared library class path and associate that library with whatever apps need access to that location.

Comment: The resources are loaded by Spring.

Comment: Where do you put them when they're in the WAR itself?  I'd assume Spring uses getResource(), but I don't know that for sure.